# Como fazer para um textbox receber apenas números

Tags: wpf

Como eu faço para um `textbox` receber apenas número, mas apenas para o WPF. Com winform eu consigo fazer, mas com WPF não consegui ainda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o evento `PreviewTextInput` do `TextBox`.

#### 1. Layout (XAML)

Adicione o evento PreviewTextInput no seu TextBox:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,181,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput"/>
```

#### 2. Code Behind (.cs)

Adicione o seguinte `using`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Adicione o método para o evento PreviewTextInput:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    e.Handled = Regex.IsMatch(e.Text, "[^0-9]+");
}
```